# PHP API for Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics

I wanna start using Google Analytics PHP API.

I found 2 libraries and I can't understand which one should I use and what is the main difference between them: **[gapi-google-analytics-php-interface](http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/)** and **[google-api-php-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)**

P.S. The main reason to use this API is requirement to work with goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`google-api-php-client` is for Google API's and not specifically for Google Analytics.

`gapi-google-analytics-php-interface` is a library that connects to your Google Analytics account and extracts data. You should use this client.

> *GAPI (said 'g,a,p,i') is the Google Analytics PHP5 Interface.*

Comment: is GAPI an official API? Coz I can't find any info about this fact and it's last realize was in 2009.

Comment: I don't think is the official API, the official API is the first one, but the second has more already built-in features.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend following this tutorial.

[Hello Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api#environment)

Although, as I recall, the latest github library did not match the script and I had to find a previous version.

If you get a bunch of include errors, check the folder structure. I ended up downloading the previous version (which matched) and have had no issues using GA API since.